# How to set another application's image into picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I'm tring to make application kind of bot anyway,
my main form have "overview" picturebox so i wanna set this picturebo's image as another application's image. i have a method but it using cpu and not very well.

Like Windows, Windows has a feature like this;

[application's overview in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcYUZ.png)

**thanks...**

Comment: [Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i dont want take application's icon. i want take aplication's image, like screenshot

Comment: check out BlindSniper's answer in [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?669866-RESOLVED-Screenshot-of-Active-Window-Area) ...his code will get you a screenshot by window title

Comment: I allready using his code, I need to use it in loop and it using cpu too much